# Can I use Observable for a simple webchat?

Tags: angular, typescript, chat

I'm new to Angular and Typescript and basically programming at all so I'm asking for your help.

I'm working on a simple webchat, where 2 predefined users can login and chat with each other.

You type your message into a textfield and send it with a button.

The button calls the function sendMessage in 'ChatComponent', this refers to the ChatService where the message is put into an array called 'messages'.

Afterwards I subscribe to my Observable in the 'ChatComponent' and I get my message on the screen. But now here's the problem: I can't see the same screen/message for the second user. Any ideas?

```js
export class ChatComponent implements OnInit {

  message: string;
  selectedUser: string;

  messages: Message[];

  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, private userService: UserService, private chatService: ChatService) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
      console.log(this.route.snapshot.paramMap.getAll('param1'));
      this.selectedUser= this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('param1');
    });
    this.getMessage();
  }

  sendMessage(text: string): void {
    this.chatService.sendMsg(text);
  }

  getMessage():void{
    this.chatService.getMessages().subscribe(messages => this.messages = messages)
  }

}
```

Also I use the code below to get a "userspecified" link/id or whatever so that I can display the name of the user in the chat later on.

```js
this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
      console.log(this.route.snapshot.paramMap.getAll('param1'));
      this.selectedUser= this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('param1');
    });
```

Here you can see where it is put together into an Observable (..I guess).

```js
export class ChatService {

  messages = [];

  constructor() {  }

  getMessages(): Observable<Message[]>{
    return of (this.messages);
  }

  sendMsg(text: string): void{
    let msg: Message = new Message();
    msg.text = text;
    this.messages.push(msg);
  }

  clear(): void{
    this.messages = [];
  }
}
```

Comment: What sort of backend are you using? You would have to send messages to the server for each client, and then have each client regularly check and pull down any new messages from the server.

Comment: @ĴošħWilliard actually I'm not using any backend at the moment. Thought there was a simple way of doing this just with frontend.

Comment: He just wants to do it in the frontend. This wont work in a reasonable and usable way. Usually to implement a chat u would need to use websockets in order to get data exchanged bidirectional and in realtime. In order to implement such a functionality u will need a backend service, which is handling subscriptions and notifications for these. Socket.io is a good lib to start with, they have also a tut on creating a small chat app --> https://socket.io/get-started/chat. But tbh when u r a beginner u will need to love the challenge ;)

Comment: Ah okay, well it isn't impossible but it is more difficult. You're looking to establish a `peer-to-peer` connection. It would be much easier to do it with a backend than trying to make p2p work if I'm being completely honest. There are node packages for p2p but I don't know of any made with Angular in mind, so I couldn't really help direct you further on that front. But its somewhere to look. But I'll reiterate, it would be much simpler to use a back end.

Comment: For my upcoming internship I got to figure out how to work with Spring Boot. So the WebSocket "Library(?)" would be my choice to connect it to my frontend? -thanks to both of you!

Comment: for creating a realtime chat app? Yes